# OmniFaces o:validateOneOrMore skips fields which was disabled conditionally

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, omnifaces

I am using primefaces 6.x with omnifaces for constructing forms.This particular form has around 20 fields texfields, dropdown values extra but has to have business logic like one or more fields needs to be filled in before the save happens. I am using omnifaces o:validateOneOrMore with the id's of all the required form fields. The issue is some of the input fields are disabled based on whether its non empty, for example

```
  <p:inputText styleClass="Fleft Wid70" maxlength="1000" id="description" 
   title="description" value="#{manageBean.myTO.desc}"
  disabled="#{manageBean.myTO.desc != null}">
</p:inputText>
```

The next time the form is processed/submitted the o:validate fires skipping the disabled inputText. Is there a way to include the field in the omnifaces validation even when its disabled?

```
   <o:validateOneOrMore id="oneOrMore" 
components="foo bar too zin ber der fir nam dil suf 
 description" message="You must enter data for atleast one of the fields" />
```

Requirement is to include all id's for validation irrespective of them being disabled or not.Please help.